# Managing and understand uWSGI in emperor mode to run my flask application

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

So I have a Flask application that I have made and i've configured uwsgi in my ini file that runs my app. I've been trying to figure out how to use emperor mode to run my app because I want to run another app with it in the future that would do the same thing. So far all the tutorials that I have seen use nginx and a conf file in etc/init. I asked my mate and he said I don't need to make a conf file because ubuntu doesn't use upstart anymore (or something like that).

Soooo my question is, I've run

```
uwsgi --emperor me.ini
```

It works and I can open the port and it works. The problem is I don't know  how to manage emperor mode and tell it what to do specifically, I know that there is a conf file but do i need to make one? Right now my command just searches for me.ini in the directory and runs it or at least that's what I think it does and i'm guessing me.ini is a vassal. I also don't know what to do with the number of processes..

My wsgi file contains.

```
from Flaskapp import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

My me.ini contains

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

http-socket = :5000
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this question already. I didn't really need a conf file, just made a vassals folder and threw in my .ini in there. You can also make a .ini for emperor mode as well to tell it what to do instead of typing it in the command line.